# Error cargar archivo CSV Pandas Python 3

Tags: python, pandas

A cargar un archivo usando Pandas la columna 14 al agregarla me genera error, yo creo porque tiene elementos muy largos.

La cargo de la sigiente manera:

```
    df4 = pd.read_csv('MAPI.csv', header=0, sep=';',usecols=[1,3,9,14,19],parse_dates = ['FOUND ON DATE '],dayfirst = True)
```

El error que tengo es el siguiente:

```
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 18: invalid continuation byte
```

Adjunto una parte del archivo:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B11sJdX_AaJBM0lvam0wdE11Yjg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Jorge, el archivo publicado lo pude importar sin error, de todas formas el el error es por un carácter que no logra interpretar correctamente como utf-8, te sugiero que edites el archivo con un editor de texto y trates de cambiar el "encoding" a utf-8. Saludos

Comment: Lo acabo de corrregir agregué esto "encoding = "ISO-8859-1""

Comment: Ok, seguramente el "encoding" default al importar es "utf-8", buena solución.

Answer (score 0):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 18: invalid continuation byte

Tu archivo contiene caracteres invalidos para el juego de caracteres utf-8, prueba utilizando otro a mi me funciona latin-1 debes poner 'latin1'

Answer (score 0):

Se debe colocar con la opción encoding así:

```
    df4 = pd.read_csv('MAPI.csv',
                      header=0,
                      sep=';',
                      encoding ='latin-1',
                      usecols=[1,3,9,14,19],
                      parse_dates=['FOUND ON DATE '],
                      dayfirst = True)
```